# Axios call stops a transition

Tags: reactjs, axios, css-transitions

So my axios calls stops currently ongoing transition like on following video:
https://youtu.be/5BCSvJpoMcs

How can I prevent axios from doing this?
That's code for that nextSlide function

```
const nextSlide = () => {
        if (isMoreItems) {
            setCarouselPage(carouselPage + 1)
            if (carouselPage === recentQuizes.length - 1) {
                apiCall(skip, limit).then(data => {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        setSkip(skip + limit)
                        setRecentQuizes([...recentQuizes, data])
                    }
                    if (data.length < 4) {
                        setIsMoreItems(false)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

and carouselPage is send to styled component that just sets transform property to translateX carouselPage * -100%

Someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it with just adding a new Wrapper and now it looks like this

```
<Wrapper carouselPage={carouselPage}>
   {recentQuizes.length > 0 &&
      recentQuizes.map(item => (
         <Container key={item[0]._id}>
            {item.map(quiz => (
               <Tile
                  key={quiz._id}
                  name={quiz.name}
                  author={quiz.author}
                  views={quiz.views}
               />
         ))}
      </Container>
   ))}
</Wrapper>
```

and Wrapper style is

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    height: inherit;
    min-width: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
    transform: ${props =>
        props.carouselPage &&
        `translateX(-${props.carouselPage * 25}%)`};
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
`
```